# Trouble running Jupiter. Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I have just downloaded Anaconda on my Mac. However when I try to run my notebook in jupyterlab it says 'No named module 'pandas' ' .. So I tried to run a pip install on pandas even though my packages listed showed that pandas was already installed. It gives me the following error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')"))': /packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(54, 'ECONNRESET')")))
```

I have tried the following code:

```
--trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org
```

Comment: Have you upgraded your pip recently?

Comment: Nope. I was just using the one that was originally installed with anaconda. pip 19.0.3

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846689/sslerror-bad-handshake-syscallerror54-econnreset/43861821#43861821

Comment: I am getting a syntax error in my terminal when I try to put this in:


bash-3.2$ self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash-3.2$                                    maxsize=maxsize,
bash-3.2$                                    block=block,
bash-3.2$                                    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'